# Setting default consistency level

Tags: scala, cassandra, phantom-dsl

Is this the right way to set the default (read and write) consistency level 
`val connector: KeySpaceDef = ContactPoints(hosts, port).withClusterBuilder { builder =>
    builder.withQueryOptions(new QueryOptions().setConsistencyLevel(ConsistencyLevel.QUORUM))
  }.keySpace("test")`

Answer (score -1):

No, the consistency level is set at protocol level per query sat setting a default one can be very dangerous. If you don't want a setting just let the defaults happen, you don't have to be explicit anywhere.

Otherwise, use consistency level where it counts:

```
class Table extends .. {

    def store(rec: Record): Future[ResultSet] = {
      insert.value(_.id, rec.id).consistencyLevel_=(ConsistencyLevel.QUORUM)
    }

}
```

Consistency levels relate to replication factors, performance, availability, and a lot of other things, so in real life you can end up spending quite a bit of time finding the perfect answer.

A global default is not really a technically feasible idea, so there's no real incentive to have such a mechanism in the driver as a result.

Comment: agree that in general a global consistency setting is not a good idea, but in our case we want to make sure we can read our own writes. That aside, would my code from above do? Would it set a default consistency level? If not, what do it do?

Comment: I agree with @EugeneMi - it's useful to set a default Consistency Level for all queries, e.g. QUORUM - manually setting this consistency level across each query adds large amounts of boilerplate, as well as introducing opportunity for subtle errors if a query is accidentally executed using ConsistencyLevel.ONE by forgetting to add the setting. Does the above code by EugeneMi work correctly or not? " If you don't want a setting just let the defaults happen, you don't have to be explicit anywhere." - ConsistencyLevel.ONE in our case is definitely not a good default (assuming that's the default).